# iOS - How to create view inside Safe Area programmatically

Tags: ios, safearealayoutguide

I have started using Safe Area after iPhone X with AutoLayout.

Now I want to draw a view from bottom of screen to all other screens and for iPhone X from bottom of safe area.

I have been `using self.view.frame.size.height` but it creates below safe area because of the obvious reason.

How can I get the safe area ending point so that I can draw the view inside Safe area?

Edit: I am not creating Safe Area Programmatically.

Comment: No I am not using safe area programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems by using `self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom` and `self.view.safeAreaInsets.top` I was able to address my problem.